# Gitlab CI - How to trigger a build only if changes happen on particular set of files

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab CI, how do you trigger a build only if changes happen on particular set of files?

Is there a way to either include or exclude certain files from triggering a build? For eg: updating `README.md, .gitignore` files should not cause a build to trigger.

Answer (score 68):

**UPDATE 2**

Only/except seem to be an unstable feature. The doc recommends using [`rules:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) instead:

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - build # replace with your build command
  rules:
    - changes:
      - /*.{java, py} # ... or whatever your file extension is
      - dockerfiles/**/* # all files under folder 'dockerfiles'
```

**UPDATE 1**:

Like [Gajus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368691/gajus) mentioned in the comments, it is now possible!

*Merge Request*: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/21981

*Documentation*: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic (Thanks to [Connor Shea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7143763/connor-shea) for the tip in the comments)

**Original post**:

<strike>No, it is not possible – not now!</strike>

I think this is the issue you are looking for: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19232 – It is a very high rated issue (over 100 thumps-up).

The milestone has changed to *Next 3-6 months*, 4 months ago. (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19232#note_31943850)
I hope we will see this function soon.

Comment: On  every README edit we need to bump version of the lib or else pipeline will fail.. i mean what are they thinking :(

Comment: Does not seem like this fires when the file in question is first added.

Comment: `only`/`accept` are deprecated in favour of `rules`

Answer (score 8):

Update: This is now possible as of 11.4, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Original post:

There's not currently any way to trigger a build in GitLab CI conditionally based on which files have been edited.

I've thought about this feature myself before, and I think it could be very useful for a number of different use cases.

The closest issue I could find for this is https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23010

Anyway, to answer your question:

You can't really do this right now – even manually – since there's no way to determine if a merge request has changed a file or not since CI has no concept of a merge request.

Pipelines "understanding" what Merge Requests are should be added sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when combines with `only` rule

```
build-web-dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build.sh
  only:
    - develop
    - changes
      web/*
      Dockerfile.web
```

Comment: `only`/`accept` are deprecated in favour of `rules`

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing the Net without any working solution, then I returned back to the official gitlab docu and tried what they write:
https://docs.gitlab.com/15.7/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges-examples

And it turned out like a working Solution in my case, the magic was just to add:
`except` rule into all related jobs, like this:

```
build:
  script: npm run build
  except:
    changes:
      - "*.md"
```

Updating docu (.md), does not trigger the whole pipeline anmore.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

That feature has been available since version 11.4.

See [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges).